# How to get the XmlTextWriter to actually write the & (without CDATA)

Tags: c#, html, xml

I am using XMLTextWriter to serialize a bunch of my objects into HTML (since HTML is basically XML), and all of my objects are able to read/write themselves as XML anyway. The method works great except for one small snag. HTML has some invalid XML such as   for a space. The TextWriter always converts this to &nbps;. I can not wrap this in a CDATA tag because the browser will simply ignore the tag, I literally need the XmlTextWriter to leave my & alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried XmlTextWriter.WriteRaw() to write those values?

I'm pretty sure this doesn't get escaped - not sure how this ties in with the code you've got though...

Comment: perfect thanks! look all over the internet and all I saw was people saying blah blah blah the & is invalid it needs to be in a CDATA... Thanks again!